# Apache Date Conditional

Tags: apache, date, time, conditional-statements

I am trying to do something like this with no luck. If date is greater than 2018 October 1st then setup this as the document root and an alias:

```
<if "expr %{TIME} -gt '20181001000001'">
 DocumentRoot "/webs/webServer/fun-2018"
 Alias /2017 /webs/webServer/fun-2017
 <Directory "/webs/webServer/fun-2017">
      <LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
          Require all denied
      </LimitExcept>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
 </Directory>
 <Directory "/webs/webServer/fun-2018">
      <LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
          Require all denied
      </LimitExcept>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
 </Directory>
</if>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to get me closer... 

<If "%{TIME}>20181001000001">

Comment: Even closer! 

<If "%{TIME} -gt 20180901000001">
Define previousperiod /webs/webServer/fun-2018
Define currentperiod /webs/webServer/fun-2019
</If>
<ElseIf "%{TIME}>20171231235999">
Define previousperiod /webs/webServer/fun-2019
Define currentperiod /webs/webServer/fun-2019
</ElseIf>
<Else>
Define previousperiod /webs/webServer/fun-2018
Define currentperiod /webs/webServer/fun-2018
</Else>

DocumentRoot "${currentperiod}"

<Directory "${previousperiod}">
..